# Retrieve a specific column / POSTCODE

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to only retrieve the POSTCODE field in this script.

Is there a way to only return this value?

```
<script>
    function LookuptableWend(query) {
        var tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr"),y=0;
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            if((y<25)&&(query)&&(tr[i].innerHTML.search(query)>-1)){
                tr[i].className="found";y+=1;
            }
                              else{tr[i].className="";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

```
<table class="lookuptable" > 
<tbody>
    <tr>
         <td>0097040K</td>
         <td>Hospital Name 1</td>
         <td>2/70 Kent Street</td>
         <td>Block 1 </td>
         <td>DEAKIN</td>
         <td>ACT</td>
         <td>2600</td>
         <td>02 6232 4793</td>
    </tr>

<script>LookuptableWend(document.getElementById("search").value);</script>
```

Comment: `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML`

Comment: Hi Peter, gave it a try but it's not returning anything.

Comment: Which column has your postcode in?  Also, what do you want to return if there are multiple rows and multiple postcodes?

Comment: Column 7 is where the postcode lives. Would ideally return a max of 25 results if it matches the postcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `querySelectorAll` with `nth-child` (comments in js below)

```js
function LookuptableWend(query) {
    var td = document.querySelectorAll(".lookuptable td:nth-child(7)"); // get all postcode cells
    
    for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
        if (td[i].innerHTML.search(query) != -1) {  // search them for your query string
           td[i].parentNode.className = "found";    // add a class to the row
        } else {
           td[i].parentNode.className = "";
        }
    }
}

LookuptableWend(2600);
```

```css
.found {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="lookuptable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0097040K</td>
      <td>Hospital Name 1</td>
      <td>2/70 Kent Street</td>
      <td>Block 1 </td>
      <td>DEAKIN</td>
      <td>ACT</td>
      <td>2600</td>
      <td>02 6232 4793</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0097040K</td>
      <td>Hospital Name 1</td>
      <td>2/70 Kent Street</td>
      <td>Block 1 </td>
      <td>DEAKIN</td>
      <td>ACT</td>
      <td>2601</td>
      <td>02 6232 4793</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0097040K</td>
      <td>Hospital Name 1</td>
      <td>2/70 Kent Street</td>
      <td>Block 1 </td>
      <td>DEAKIN</td>
      <td>ACT</td>
      <td>2600</td>
      <td>02 6232 4793</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```